Hereditarily countable sets in Antifounded ZF
A set $x$ is hereditarily countable when every membership-descendant of $x$ (including $x$ itself) is countable.
In this paper, Jech proved in ZF that the class of all hereditarily countable sets is a set.  (See here and here and here for developments of this result.)
Can this be shown in the variant of ZF that uses Aczel's Antifoundation instead of Foundation?
Another question that I think is equivalent: does ZF prove the existence of a final coalgebra for the countable powerset functor?

Which antifoundation axiom do you mean, Aczel's? (There are others.)

Edited (but personally I think it's fine to just call it Antifoundation).

The axiom is usually denoted AFA, and the theory ZFA.

ZFA is also used for atoms.  I learnt "Anti-ZF" from Thomas Forster.

Yes, actually I prefer ZFA for urelement set theory, since I prefer to call them "atoms", but unfortunately, the "urelement" terminology and ZFU notation is entrenched. Since this also resolves the ambiguity with anti-foundation, I have given up and now write ZFU.

ZFU (or at least ZFCU) is also used to include the Universe axiom.

I haven't seen that. That is very bad notation, since we already have ZFC+UA. What a mess!

@JoelDavidHamkins Ah yes, ZFC + a proper class of urelements (unlimited atoms :P).

Oh no! A complete, utter mess.

OK, in light of this, I am going back on my previous concession. Since I prefer to call them atoms, not urelements, I shall use henceforth ZFA for set theory with atoms. If you want Aczel's theory, you have to write AFA for the axiom and ZFAFA or something like that for the theory. With apologies to Forster, I find Anti-ZF to be a nonstarter, since it doesn't even reference wellfounded issues and expresses unnecessary negativity toward ZF.

Jech's argument relies quite heavily on having an explicit description of the ranks of hereditarily countable sets so that you can get an upper bound, so in any case I wouldn't expect it to generalise easily to cover this case.

I have edited the question to avoid the name "Anti-ZF".  No negativity towards ZF was intended.

@NoahSchweber  My preference is to call Aczel's axiom "Antifoundation" and Boffa's "Superuniversality".   I would rather not give them similar names, since they are utterly different.

@JoelDavidHamkins I personally would save ZFC + UA for a hypothesis that isn’t just a proper class of inaccessibles!

But the universe axiom is quite established in category theory with this meaning. And we have other ways of expressing stronger concepts, such as Ord is Mahlo etc. But note: Ord is never definably weakly compact in light of https://www.jstor.org/stable/26600314.

@JoelDavidHamkins I think Gabe is pointing to  the use of "UA" for the ultrapower axiom.

Ah, that's right, I forgot! (Sorry, Gabe.)

Update. This answer does not answer the question that was asked, since Jech is using what had seemed to me as an idiosyncratic definition of hereditary countable. But upon reflection, I find his definition completely natural in a context without AC. Namely, he defines that a set is hereditary countable when it is countable and every element of the transitive closure is countable. In short, the set itself and every set appearing hereditarily in it is countable. (This is not equivalent, even in ZF as Jech proves, to saying that the transitive closure of the set is countable.)
If a negative answer to the question is possible, I suspect it will arise by finding a model of ZF in which AC fails badly and using it to interpret a model of ZFA where there is proper class of inequivalent accessible pointed graphs such that every node has only countably many children. I have wondered whether Gitik's model, in which every infinite limit ordinal has cofinality $\omega$, will be helpful for this.

Original answer:
In ZFA every set is determined by the underlying accessible pointed graph, the $\in$ relation on the transitive closure, and the AFA axiom asserts that isomorphic graphs will give rise to the same set.
Thus, the hereditarily countable sets will arise from the countable graphs, which is a set by the argument you mentioned. And so in ZFA the hereditarily countable sets will form a set.
It is interesting to note that, being countable, the underlying graphs of any hereditarily countable set can be realized within the well-founded part of the universe, even if the set that they name is not well-founded. So the hereditarily countable sets in ZFA arise from a functional image of the well-founded hereditarily countable sets, namely, the graph relations on $\omega$.
This argument doesn't work at all in the Boffa antifoundation theory, which has a proper class of distinct Quine atoms, all of which are countable. However, even in that theory, there are up to isomorphism only a set of hereditarily countable sets, since they are determined up to isomorphism by the underlying graph relation.

The pointed graph representing a hereditarily countable set x is given by the transitive closure of {x}, which can't be proved countable.

? I take it that a set is hereditarily countable means that its transitive closure is countable. And this implies $\text{TC}({x})$ also is countable, since there is only one more point.

Oh this is not what I meant by hereditarily countable.  I will have to edit the question.

See the first sentence of Jech's paper.  I am using his definition.

Very weird. Jech's definition seems just wrong, even in ZFC, since every element of the transitive closure of $\omega_1$ is countable, but we don't say $\omega_1$ is hereditarily countable. It isn't even countable. Unless by TC(x) he means the smallest transitive set containing $x$ as an element, that is, the closure of ${x}$. This must be what he means, in order to get the second sentence of his paper true. This is definitely nonstandard meaning for transitive closure.

Jech begins "A countable set $S$".

Ah, that explains it. Sorry, I am now understanding the point of the question...

I edited for clarity.  Your answer is of course correct for the way you were previously reading the question.

Ultimately, this is a non-AC question rather than a anti-foundation question, since my answer works very well in ZFCA. What you need to do for a counterexample, if this is possible, is cook up a very badly behaved model of ZF in which AC fails, and use it interpret a similarly bad model of ZFA.

I have an idea to use Gitik's model of ZF in which every ordinal has cofinality $\omega$. It is tempting to consider the graphs arising from these ordinals by pointing down to cofinal $\omega$ sequences, and if you do this hereditarily it will be hereditarily countable in Jech's sense (which I now agree is natural for the ZF context). But these will be wf, so I'm not sure how to use this idea fully.

And by the way, I now agree that Jech's notion of hereditarily countable is very natural in the context without AC. It is a countable set such that every set arising in its hereditary membership relation is countable. I completely retract my previous remarks on this.
